# Equalizing a circular array

Tags: arrays, algorithm

First of all, it is NOT a homework problem, it's a interview question(Alibaba).

**The original problem is "Transport goods between warehouses to make all warehouses have the same inventory and all these warehouses make up an circle."**

I abstract out the problem as below:

There is a circular **integer** array, now you need to **equalize** the circular array(i.e., you need to make every element in the circular array have the same value). So you must "move some  amount of value" from one element to another.

For example, there is a circular array:

`c_array = {1, 2, 3}`, `c_array[0] == 1`, `c_array[1] == 2`, `c_array[2] == 3`.

To equalize the circular array, you must "move" `1` from `c_array[2]` to `c_array[0]`.

There are some rules:

1. Movement **MUST** be between adjacent elements;
2. Amount of movement must be integer;
3. Moving `k` from one element to another costs `k`;

Another example:

`c_array = {1, 2, 7, 6}`, `c_array[0] == 1`, `c_array[1] == 2`, `c_array[2] == 7`, `c_array[3] == 6`.

The solution is:

Move `2` from  `c_array[3]` to  `c_array[0]`, cost `2`;

Move `3` from  `c_array[2]` to  `c_array[1]`, cost `3`;

Move `1` from  `c_array[1]` to  `c_array[0]`, cost `1`;

Total cost is `6`.

The question is to find a solution with minimum cost. If there are no valid solution, output "NO". Give your algorithm in details(just explain your algorithm, do not need to code).

Comment: ok, seems like a homework to me

Comment: @undefined It says interview question.

Comment: @undefined I've said it was a interview question. Can you see that.

Comment: @JohnWillemse I did not give the answer in the interview. It does not matter what language. Do you have any idea?

Comment: No, I don't have an answer ready, but if you do not provide code for what you have tried so far, then most likely this question will be closed by the moderators. SO is not for having your homework/interview questions done for you without any effort from your side.

Comment: @JohnWillemse Ok, you still think that it is a homework.I have nothing to say.Maybe my English is too crummy or I have post the question at a wrong place.

Comment: Your English is fine. I understand this is not homework, but an interview question. However, _StackOverflow_ is not a place where you can post a theoretical problem and have people code complete answers for you. You have to show some effort yourself; you are the one with the problem. If you get stuck on a piece of code, we will be more than happy to help you!

Comment: i think the rules are not valid. especially rule 3 is wrong, which has cost O(1) not k, equalizing in my circular array would cost O(N) where N is the current size of the array, just read the value to be used for equalizing in O(1) and iterate through all N elements and assign each with cost O(1) = O(N)

Comment: @JohnWillemse I've tagged this problem with "algorithm", so I do not have any problem to coding it out if I know the algorithm, I just have no idea about the algorithm, I do not need your code at all.

Comment: @AlexWien Here the "cost" is not the same to time complexity.

Comment: @ cost k is still invalid, never an int value of 3 costs 3, when an int value of 8 costs 8, this is wrong, all int values costs the same

Comment: @alexwien: you can define the cost function any way you like, can't you ?

Comment: no, if its an integer array then not, the costs are defined by the programming language.  if it is an custom object, then yes.

Comment: it seems that now i have understood what the interviewer asked, but you have badly expressed. you want to equalizen the array such that the summ of all values are still the same but equal distributed.

Comment: @alexwien: i think 'cost' does not mean cpu cycles but a domain-specific measure. imsrch, can you please clarify this aspect ?

Comment: @AlexWien I am sorry for my crummy English. I have reedit the problem.

Comment: ok, now it is clearly expressed.

Comment: flawed answer deleted.

Answer (score 5):

If you transform circular array into a graph, where each node corresponds to some array element, node's supply/demand is equal to difference between element's value and average value, each node is connected to its two neighbors with an edge, edge capacity is unlimited, cost of each edge is 1, you get exactly the Minimum Cost Flow problem.

You could find several algorithms for solving it on this page: ["Minimum Cost Flow, Part 2: Algorithms"](http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=minimumCostFlow2).

Comment: I cann't express how grateful I am for your answer, at least you do not think it is a homework. At first everybody think it is a homework and many vote-downs.

Answer (score 0):

I got the exact same problem in the round 1 of hackwithinfy 2020 held yesterday, I were able to submit the solution of this problem successfully and got full(75) marks, although I do not have the code with me, I will try to explain the algorithm if you face any difficulty, I will surely help.

So, basically what we need to do is to equalise all the elements of the array, so we will find the cost of converting the whole array into all the different elements and print the minimum of all the costs as our answer.

For example 1 1 2 3
if this is our array, we will try and find the cost of replacing all the elements of the array into 1, then the cost of conversion of all the elements of the array into 2 and similarly to 3, then we will find the minimum of these costs. As we can see converting all the elements of the array into 1 will be least costly.

Now to implement this, I used a map of integer and a vector, i.e map > map1. Now, while taking input, I mapped all the elements of the array to the vector of their occurrences in the array, now I found the difference between adjacent occurrences also considering diff b/w last and first(as the array is circular) and found maximum of these differences, then if the difference is even, then cost is difference/2 otherwise difference-1/2. There are corner cases such that when there is only one occurrence of an element, it can also be tackled easily by taking maximum of (length - index - 1) & (index).

Now the minimum of all these costs will give us the answer.

If you have any doubt, comment below, I will explain to you more briefly with some more examples.